# xamarin.form binding twoway for object properties not working

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, binding, xamarin.forms, model

```
myview
<Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Source="contactIcon.png" />
<Entry Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  Text="{Binding 
SelectedContact.FNAME,Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="First Name" />
<Entry Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  Text="{Binding 
SelectedContact.LNAME,Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Last Name"/>
<Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Source="calIcon.png" />
<Entry Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding 
SelectedContact.PHONE,Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Mobile" 
Keyboard="Telephone"/>
<Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Source="emailIcon.png" />
<Entry Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding 
SelectedContact.EMAIL,Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Email" Keyboard="Email"/>
<Entry Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding 
SelectedContact.BALANCE,Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Email" 
Keyboard="Email"/>

Contact model
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FNAME { get; set; }
    public string LNAME { get; set; }
    public string PHONE { get; set; }
    public string EMAIL { get; set; }
    public Double BALANCE { get; set; }

ContactViewModel
private Contact _selectedContact;
public Contact SelectedContact{get { return _selectedContact; }set{ 
_selectedContact = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
```

OneWay binding is working but i want twoway binding. If i change  the text or modify the text in the firstname entry then it should change the FNAME property of SelectedContact

Answer (score 1):

```
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(String property)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
    {
        MemberExpression expression = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
        RaisePropertyChanged(expression.Member.Name);
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Try this in your view for property change

`RaisePropertyChanged(()=>YourPropertyName);`

Answer (score 0):

You had to implement INotifyPropertyChanged which is main interface for two way binding.At your viewmodel class you had to implement like this way

```
 public class ContactViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
 { 
   private Contact _selectedContact;
   public Contact SelectedContact
   { 
      get 
       { return _selectedContact; }
      set
       { _selectedContact = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(); 
       } 
    }
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;  
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {  
        PropertyChanged ? .Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));  
    }
}
```

At your MainPage()

```
public MainPage() {  
        InitializeComponent();  
        vm = new ContactViewModel();  
        BindingContext = vm;  
    }
```

Comment: thanks delta12 yes i have impemented inotifypropertyChanged as you have written. The main problem is twoway binding. One way binding is doing well. I want both way binding which is not working

Comment: did you applied PropertyChangedEventHandler

Comment: please paste detailed code of your ContactViewModel

Comment: public class ContactViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
          {
        public ContactViewModel(){ }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] 
          string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
private Contact _selectedContact;
public Contact SelectedContact
  { 
   get 
   { return _selectedContact; }
   set
   {  _selectedContact = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(); 
   } 
  }}